# Скролл к тексту на странице( в качестве текса рендеринг pdf c помощью pdf.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Нужно оптимизировать одно старое приложение. Есть поиск по странице. По клику на найденом должен происходит скролл к этому тексту на странице.
Это так реализовано. Но почему-то не работает. подскажите пожалуйста
Есть ещё один момент поиск чуствителен к регистру. Я так понимаю из-за :contains . Чем его можно заменить?
Спасибо

```
$("#autocompleateitem2").on("filterablebeforefilter", function (e, data) {
    var $ul = $(this),
        $input = $(data.input),
        value = $input.val(),
        html = "";
    $ul.html("");
    if (value && value.length > 2) {
        $ul.html("<li><div class='ui-loader'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-loading'></span></div></li>");
        $ul.listview("refresh");
        var a = $input.val();
        $('.textLayer div:contains(' + a + ')')
            .map(function () {
                html += "<li><a href='#' title='" + $(this).html() + "'>" + $(this).html() + "</a></li>";
            });
        $ul.html(html);
        $ul.listview("refresh");
        $ul.trigger("updatelayout");
    }
    $("#autocompleateitem2 a").click(function () {
        var elementClick = $(this).attr("title").toString();
        console.log(elementClick);
        console.log(elementClick.isPrototypeOf());
        var element = $( elementClick );
        console.log(element);
        $('#viewer').scrollTo(element, {duration: 'slow', offsetTop: '60'});
    });
});
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, ошибки есть? в консль элемент выводит?

Comment: Да " Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:"  дальше   текст по которому я кликал

Comment: добавьте в вопрос полный текст или скрин пожалуйста

Comment: добавил скриншот

Comment: предлагаю продолжить обсуждение в чате https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63579/pdf-c--pdf-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас проблема с поисковым элементом. Как правильно вернуть его написал в js коде, так же решение с регистром в начале js кода, придется создавать свой собственный :Contains (название такое же, только с большой буквы)

```js
//Для не чувствиетльности к регистру создается вот такой самодельный contains
jQuery.expr[":"].Contains = jQuery.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
    return function( elem ) {
        return jQuery(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
    };
});

function search(){
    //То же саме. что у вас  из атрибута
    var searchString = $('#search').val();
    //Находит элемент через свой Contains
    var element = $('#viewer div:Contains("'+searchString+'")');
    
    $('#viewer').animate({
            scrollTop: $(element).offset().top + $('#viewer').scrollTop() - 30
        }, 2000); 
}

//ваш код должен выглядить примерно так:
$("#autocompleateitem2 a").click(function () {
    var elementClick = $(this).attr("title");
    //Если прямо в блоке #viewer находятся те самые div для поиска, если нет надо прописать путь к родителю от viewer например #viewer>.wrapperForSearch>div:Contains("'+elementClick+'")
    var element = $('#viewer div:Contains("'+elementClick+'")');
    $('#viewer').animate({
            scrollTop: $(element).offset().top + $('#viewer').scrollTop() - 30
        }, 2000); 
});
```

```css
#viewer{
    max-height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.search2{
    margin-top: 1000px;
}
.search1{
    margin-top: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search"><button onclick="search()">заскролить</button>
<div id="viewer">
    <div><p>roll</p></div>
    <div class="search1"><p>test1</p></div>
    <div class="search2"><p>test2</p></div>
</div>
```